# In QT creator how to automatically add breakpoints to all methods in a cpp file or whole project?

Tags: qt, debugging, gdb, qt-creator, breakpoints

I have downloaded a open source Qt project & I want to understand it by debugging. I would like to add break points to all methods present in a file or if possible to all files in the project.

Is there any shortcut command/setting in QT creator by which I can add break points in one go instead of manually clicking in every method?

Comment: Just put a breakpoint on the 'main' function and debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the break point for all the functions of a given file(Let's say filename is test.c), you can use like below

```
rbreak test.c:.
```

Please see this link as well for break points 
    https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html